# How to customize the style of CheckBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, templates, checkbox, styles

I'm just begin study WPF, so I'm unfamiliar with style and template. 
I want to customize a `CheckBox` with a `Image` and two `Labels` like this:

[image]

[image]

How can I do?

.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Width="150" 
                  Height="40" 
                  Margin="4" 
                  Padding="4,0,0,0">
            <Grid Background="#FFEEEEEE" 
                  Width="130"
                  MaxWidth="Infinity">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Margin="5" 
                       Source="/WpfApplication4;component/Images/LargeIcon.png" />
                <Label Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="1" 
                       Padding="0">
                    Label1
                </Label>
                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1" 
                       Padding="0">
                    Label2
                </Label>
            </Grid>
        </CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Edit:**

.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication4.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2006" 
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyCheckBox" 
               TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <DockPanel Background="#FFEEEEEE" 
                                   Height="34"
                                   Width="130">
                            <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                   Source="/WpfApplication4;component/Images/LargeIcon.png"
                                   Margin="5" />
                            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Label1" />
                            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Label2" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

used in .xaml

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" />
```

Something be presented, but the small grid is disappeared, like this:

[image]

How can I do?

Comment: I can't find somebody's answer. What's wrong? Could it be deleted carelessly?

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DockPanel` may be the best option for this layout

Example:

```
<CheckBox>
   <DockPanel Height="34">
      <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="/WpfApplication4;component/Images/LargeIcon.png" Margin="2" />
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Label1" />
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Label2" />
   </DockPanel>
</CheckBox>
```

### Edit:

It looks like you still want to use the default `Checkbox` `Template` but just override the `Content` in your `Style`.

Example:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DockPanel Background="#FFEEEEEE" Width="130"  MaxWidth="Infinity">
                <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="Capture.png" Margin="5" />
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Label1" />
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Label2" />
            </DockPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank u very much. Can I move the small grid to other position in the panel?

Comment: And how dynamically modify the text of the TextBox in the CheckBox?

Comment: I was trying to do similar, however my DataGrid is dynamically generated, and checkbox is first column in it. So I am trying to set it up style like this.

```<UserControl.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"><Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" /> </Style>
</Usercontrol.Resoruces>``` 
Not using key since I am fine to make all checkboxes vertically center. But this is not working. Any hints?